# How do show the target ID in flask_table LinkCol?

Tags: flask

I have created a table using flask_table and I have set the type of one of its columns to be LinkCol. My problem is that on every row of the table, the link (which seems to be correct) is printing the name of the column rather than the ID to which it points. I would prefer to the see the key in that column.

Here's what I see...
[image: h]

What I want, though, is to see the ID number for each record in the ID column, not the word "ID". Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code...

```
    tbl_obj = create_table('tst_tbl')
    for col in col_names:
    if col == url_col:
        tbl_obj.add_column(col, LinkCol(name=url_col, endpoint=url, url_kwargs=dict(ID=url_col)))
    else:
        tbl_obj.add_column(col, Col(col))
```

Any ideas for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this in the [GitHub issues log](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/issues/19)...

*If you set attr='my_attribute_name' on your LinkCol, it should use the value from that attribute as the text for the link. It uses the name of the column as a fallback. Unlike with other columns, it does not borrow the attribute that you give the column in the table class to get the attribute from the item for the td.*

Worked for me! Here's my new code...

```
    tbl_obj = create_table('tst_tbl')
    for col in col_names:
        if col == url_col:
            tbl_obj.add_column(col, LinkCol(name=url_col, endpoint=url, url_kwargs=dict(ID=url_col), attr=(url_col)))
        else:
            tbl_obj.add_column(col, Col(col))
```

And the resulting screen shot...
[image]

Thanks!